# A bunch of error "An error occurred using a transaction. " in serilog file

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-5, serilog

Serilog tracks a bunch of errors repeatedly with the below description:

> An error occurred using a transaction.

and there is no more detail about where these errors happened. I search a lot to find an answer but no one was helpful to solve.
Can anybody give me an idea when this error will happen?

### UPDATE:

this error occurs frequently even when there is no request on my application.

Comment: Which Database provider?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv SQL Server

Comment: Well, I have no idea what happened. Try to better log exceptions with stack trace.